# What is "ж" by itself?

Tags: значения, буквы

Google says "ж" is one of 10 single-lettered words in the Russian alphabet. I've tried searching what "ж" means on its own, but most of the results were either written entirely in Russian (which I don't fully understand) or were unhelpful. Also I don't have access to Wikipedia or Wiktionary because it's blocked on my computer (it's a school device so I can't change the settings).

Comment: apart from Wikipedia and Wiktionary (which, quite honestly, are very strange sites to block in educational institutes) there are other resources one can google - if your question is about how it's pronounced this can give you idea - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NgoPrE7QYNU

(in English there's no such phoneme)

Comment: ж by itself is a short form of же

Comment: @shabunc Thanks for the reference but my question is more about the meaning of the word, not the pronunciation. Wikipedia is blocked because my teachers think it's unreliable, though I find it can be quite helpful.

Comment: @Anixx Thanks so much!

Comment: `Ж` by itself is a sign on women's restroom, too.

Comment: @DK [Это ж-ж-ж неспроста!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2emZSf9GNU0)

Comment: Some time people say "полная ж !", it means - holy crap! ж is short for жопа word. So - полная ж = полная жопа = everything is bad